# How to know if a quadrilateral is circumscribed

Tags: quadrilateral

Let's say I have a quadrilateral that is convex and I know the points that are forming it. How can I know if the quadrilateral is circumscribed?
Is it true that a quadrilateral is circumscribed if and only if the sum of opposite sides are equal?

[image: Click to view the image]

In my case, picture above, only if $AB+CD=AC+BD$?

Comment: I should be called **tangential** quadrilateral.  See the classification [**here**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RobeF.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true. It's [Pitot's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_theorem) and its converse.

See http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Pitot.shtml